# Wrap all saga actions in a common generator function

Tags: redux, redux-saga, saga

I am using redux-sage in my application and below is my code

```
export default function* () {
    yield takeLatest(ActionTypes.VALIDATE_INPUT, checkForInputValidity);
    yield takeLatest(ActionTypes.ON_REFRESH, onRefresh);
    yield takeLatest(ActionTypes.ON_SUBMIT, onSubmit);
}
```

Is there a way to make sure I call a common generator function before any action is handled. For example,
whenever I dispatch some action, I want to update a variable in redux-state. this is common across all actions. What I am trying to avoid here is to duplicate some piece of common code in every action handler

Answer (score 1):

You can call `take` with no arguments or with `'*'` in order to match all actions, per the [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/).

The part that might get tricky (though still totally doable!) is getting the correct order of generator functions.  Is it important the universal generator is run *before* the other generators, or is it ok if they are all run at once asynchronously?  The docs on [concurrency](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Concurrency.html), [`fork` vs `spawn`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/ForkModel.html), and [running tasks in parallel](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RunningTasksInParallel.html) might illustrate the difference.

Untested, but I think this is what you want:

```
import {all, takeLatest, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* universal(action) {
  // do something
  // if dispatching anything here, make sure that the dispatched action doesn't get picked up again and create an infinite loop
}

export default function* () {
  // univeral generator is called with a blocking yield
  yield takeEvery( '*', universal);
  // run individual generators in parallel to each other
  yield all ([
    takeLatest(ActionTypes.VALIDATE_INPUT, checkForInputValidity),
    takeLatest(ActionTypes.ON_REFRESH, onRefresh),
    takeLatest(ActionTypes.ON_SUBMIT, onSubmit),
  ]);
}
```

Alternatively, you could write some sort of custom middleware.

Comment: Thanks Linda for the solution here. My use case is to first execute a universal generator function

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple reducer function](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers) which skips action type check and  track all the actions, and i.e. return the current timestamp:

`export default () => + new Date()`